# Struct embedding of interfaces, panic: runtime error

Tags: go, struct, interface, go-interface

I'm trying an example related to struct embedding of interfaces

```
// https://talks.golang.org/2014/go4java.slide#52
// Struct embedding of interfaces
// https://play.golang.org/p/SYiZ7M1OEhU

package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

// net.Conn has Read and Write

type loopBack struct {
    net.Conn
    buf bytes.Buffer
}

func (c *loopBack) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    fmt.Println("loopBack Read")
    return 0, nil 
}

func main() {

    loop := loopBack{}
    loop.Read(nil)
    loop.Write(nil)                                                                           
}
```

and the `Write` method is undefined, so I get this runtime error

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0xffffffff addr=0x0 pc=0xe28ca]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox812386031/main.go:28 +0x6a
```

Exist some way to validate it at compile time?

link to code

https://play.golang.org/p/SYiZ7M1OEhU

Comment: No, you cannot check for runtime panics at compile time, or we wouldn't need runtime panics. Perhaps create a constructor for your `loopBack` type?

Comment: The `Write` method isn't undefined - it's defined by the embedded `Conn`. The problem is simply that the `Conn` is `nil`.

Comment: If the problem *were* that it was undefined, that *would* be caught at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is *not* the same as saying "`loopBack implements net.Conn`".
To get compile-time error(s) about the missing method – and the mismatched `Read()`, too – declare `loop`'s type:
(And don't embed [`net.Conn`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn) in `loopBack`)

```golang
func main() {
  var loop net.Conn = loopBack{}
```

Comment: That's a completely different thing, though... embedding an interface type is common, and useful. Just initialise the `Conn` field, job done.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem True, it depends on how one reads the question, whether it's "How to make this code work" or "How to get a compile-time error that it won't work"

Comment: Given how the `net.Conn` interface is far bigger than `Read` and `Write` alone, I'm taking it the OP wants a `net.Conn` with a buffer fields for whatever reason (maybe mocking?). Either way, that's up to the OP to specify, because when it comes to mocking, there's many better ways to go about it

Comment: He did ask 
"Exist some way to validate it at compile time?".
But, it's hard to tell. Also because it's from a go4java talk, I assumed he wanted to express explicit `implements` in Go

Comment: Yeah, I see how you interpreted the question now. I brushed that bit off as an X-Y problem (as in: OP thinks embedded interfaces somehow force compile-time checks on the struct in which he's embedding)

Answer (score 0):

Golang doesn't require *exlicit* interface implementations. What you do here:

```
type loopBack struct {
    net.Conn
    buf bytes.Buffer
}
```

Is the similar to:

```
type loopBack struct{
    Conn net.Conn
    buf bytes.Buffer
}
```

`net.Conn` being an interface type, the first field of your `loopBack` type can be anything that implements the `net.Conn` interface, which is of course more than `Read` and `Write` alone ([see here](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn)).

The advantage of embedding types is that the fields and receiver functions (name conflicts aside) can be accessed directly on the types that embeds them.

With an embedded `net.Conn` field, you can indeed write:

```
loop.Write(nil)
```

**If** the `Conn` field is initialised (otherwise, its value is `nil`). Changing the declaration to the second version, `loop.Write` won't work, you'll have to write:

```
loop.Conn.Write(nil)
```

Type embedding is very powerful, but there's a number of gotcha's when you first get started. Thankfully, there's an entire paragraph explaining embedding on the [effective go doc](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding)

Anyway, as stated, you are able to call functions, and access fields (if you're embedding a struct type instead of an interface). There is one thing, though: the field must be initialised correctly!

And that's where you went wrong: You still have to *initialise* your `Conn` part of the `loopBack` variable, otherwise what you're doing is the same as:

```
net.Conn(nil).Write(nil)
```

Which, naturally, results in a panic (nil pointer dereference)...

For example:

```
conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:80")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("failed to dial localhost: %+v", err)
}
loop := loopBack{
    Conn: conn,
}
loop.Write(nil) // same as conn.Write(nil)
```

Failing to set the `net.Conn` embedded field is akin to doing something like this:

```
s := make([]*int, 10) // make slice of 10 pointers to int
fmt.Println(len(s)) // outputs 10
*s[0]++ // add 1 to first element PANICS
```

The 10 elements in the slice exist, but they've all been initialised to `nil`